# I get the error "'user' is null" printing the name of the person who sent the message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is the code:

```
client.on('message', message => {

const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("752608694641885414");
let user1 = message.author
let name = guild.member(user1).user.username
console.log(name)

}
```

I'm getting this error when trying to write the name of the member who is sending a message:

```
app[worker.1]: let name = guild.member(user1).user.username
app[worker.1]:                               ^
app[worker.1]: 
app[worker.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
```

Comment: It doesn't say "'user' is null." It says "cannot read property 'user' **of** null." `guild.member(user1)` is null.

Comment: So how can I do this, can you give a clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not assign `name` until `guild.member(user1)` has a valid value. It is currently returning `null` hence trying to retrieve `user` from it will be useless.

Be more cautious on your assignment and say:

```
if (guild.member(user1) !== null)
    name = guild.member(user1).user.username
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: I think your answer is misleading, `Guild.member` is a synchronous function, it doesn't need to "fully load". The reason it is happening is because the message that the bot responded to simply isn't in the `guild` that was fetched from the hardcoded snowflake.

Comment: @yifansong thanks for your comment, I edited the answer to accommodate your feedback. Cheers.